# Magento2 customer/address/new

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend, customer-address

I'm getting a blank page (without content, sidebars etc exists) on `customer/address/new` action using an custom theme.

What I want to do is to implement that new page under `customer/address/new`, that's the standard action when customer has no addresses.

So I've created an xml `customer_address_new.xml` in which I've specified an template file (and other stuff copied from the `edit` action), but it doesn't work, I've got same effect as without my layout and template files.

The layout file: `<theme>/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_address_new.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account" />
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_page_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="is_highlighted" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit" name="customer_address_new" template="address/new.phtml" cacheable="true" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

What's going on?

Comment: please check updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missing **layout="1column"** in your customer_address_new.xml file,

please insert layout inside  node,

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account" />
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_page_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="is_highlighted" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit" name="customer_address_new" template="address/new.phtml" cacheable="true" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: sorry, but that's not working, maybe something is wrong with the controller:

`public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward $resultForward */
        $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
        return $resultForward->forward('form');
    }`, I'm not sure what's the forward factory doing.

Comment: Have you add 1column inside page tag?

Comment: yes, I did

*this text is only for satisfy the lenght requirement*

Comment: whats the issue you have faced now after apply changes?

Comment: it's the same, a page without content, now I've noticed theres an error while loading the page: `[2016-10-24 10:32:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'address/edit.phtml' in module: 'Webinse_Customer' block's name: 'customer_address_edit' [] []` might it be caused by that?

Comment: But you have passed address/new.phtml template not edit.phtml template first check template name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47310/discussion-between-roomy-and-rakesh).

Comment: the Rakesh answer is correct, the cause was an error in the `Webinse_Customer` module.